# python termination error when ctypes dll calls printf

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am developing a python system with some core dlls accessed via ctypes.  I have reduced the problem to this condition: execute a module that loads (no need to call) two dlls, one of which calls printf -- this error will occur in exit.

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way.   Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

My environment:
 - Windows 7, SP1
 - Python 2.7.8
 - MinGW v 3.20

This test case is adapted from a tutorial on writing dlls with MinGW:

```
/* add_core.c */
__declspec(dllexport) int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

/* sub_core.c */
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllexport) int sum(int a, int b) {
    printf("Hello from sub_core.c");
    return a - b;
}
```

prog.py

```
import ctypes
add_core_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('add_core.dll')
add_core_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('sub_core.dll')
```

```
> make
gcc -Wall -O3 -g -ansi -c  add_core.c -o add_core.o
gcc -g -L. -ansi             -shared add_core.o -o add_core.dll
gcc -Wall -O3 -g -ansi -c  sub_core.c -o sub_core.o
gcc -g -L. -ansi             -shared sub_core.o -o sub_core.dll

>python prog.py

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

and pops up a message dialog to the same effect: "python.exe has stopped working ...".

Note that the programs execute as expected and produce normal output.  This error at termination is just a big nuisance I'd like to be rid of.

Answer (score 0):

the same happens for:
Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1
Python 2.7.11
mingw32-g++.exe 5.3.0